# AJAX query fails due to missing DEFINE variable in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am new to AJAX/jQuery with PHP.

I am trying to call a PHP script via AJAX using XMLHttpRequest or jQuery. In both cases the call fails because the php file I am calling into contains on the very first row the following check

```
if (!defined("SOMETHING")) { die("Error. You cannot access this file directly");}
```

which causes that my call fails, because this variable is not defined in this case as I am calling from the outside. This condition just checks if the caller is the same web application or wheather the call comes from outside (then it will be denied).

Is there a workaround for it without removing this check? Can I somehow set this expected variable using AJAX/jQuery?

Is there a way how to call specific PHP method via AJAX without calling into the whole PHP file?

Thanks in advance
Tomas

Comment: Call it through a similar path as you call your other web application actions. Your define is probably set through a bootstrap, so you need to call it that way.

Comment: @ datasage: this is unfortunatel not possible. Calling the bootstrapper directly causes that some other things are written to the output and shown on the place where I am expecting the results of the Ajax call. Unfortunately, I am not able to change the bootstrapper so that it behaves differently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm... you can do it, but I am not sure if this is secure or the way you would like it to be.

Your jQuery should post a variable with `GET` or `POST`, which you should check on PHP side. If you have received that variable, then define `SOMETHING`.

Here is your jQuery, using the `POST` method:

```
$.post('ajax.php', {SOMETHING: true}, function(ret){
    // do whatever you like with the return here
});
```

Here is your PHP, which will define `SOMETHING` if it receives a `$_POST` request with the variable `SOMETHING` in it.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['SOMETHING'])){
    define('SOMETHING', true);
}
if (!defined("SOMETHING")) { die("Error. You cannot access this file directly");}

// do anything you like here
?>
```

Comment: This would create a security hole into my app which is what I do not want...I think I try to find some other way to solve it, but thanks a lot!

Comment: I gave you a heads up on that. It will definitely do that. You can separate your server side ajax handler, though, and use it safely. Or, just reach the ajax handler via the path, which will define the variable.